# Is it worth to micro optimize with redux stores in react

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux, micro-optimization

**Scenario:** Form with multiple inputs, selects, files etc... Automatically generated from configuration. Only functional react components.

**Type 1:** Form full state is stored in redux store, connected with react-redux.
Every time value in form is changed, new dispatch to store. As result, every forms input field receives and update to state, even if value is not changed, in particle input field.

**Type 2:** When form is created, every input field receives own store (Auto generate). On update, input field receives only new state for particle input field.

So in the end, is it worth to create Type 2 scenario, or there will be no benefits? Im new to redux, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question comes up pretty frequently in the Redux community, and there are benefits to type 2, if you are interested in optimizing your rendering. It definitely helps when you begin to render more than a few hundred items and need to update only a one or a few at a time, which would be the case for an input. Take a look at this list of links for Redux performance:

https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance

I find that this slideshow is useful in demonstrating your two scenarios (using a checkbox rather than a text input), along with one more solution.

http://somebody32.github.io/high-performance-redux/